# Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::edit() bug?

Tags: laravel-5, php-7

So I have this restful route `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');`

I have altered the **edit** controller method like so:

`public function edit(Request $request, customer_user $user,  $id)`

with this, I get `Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\UserController::edit()`

`customer_user` is a model.

But if I add `$id = null` in the controller method **I get the desired outcome**.

But again, if i do this

`dd($id)` with the url `http://x/3/edit` it says "null" and does not give me the number.

But my model `dd($user->take(1)->first())` shows the correct one from the url!?

I am really confused by this and couldnt find anyone with a similar problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need $id here

```
public function edit(Request $request, customer_user $user,  $id)
```

Why ? - when you use `Route::resource('user', 'UserController');` laravel create routes and one of them is `/user/{user}/edit` with GET method here is one placeholder. by default when you create resource controller the edit method is like this `public function edit($id)` and the value of $id is set from whatever passed as `{user}`

But in your edit method `edit(Request $request, customer_user $user,  $id)`

> -* When a method is called all the parameter must be given unless the parameter holds default value
>
> -As your url is `http://x/3/edit` laravel passes the Request as first param value
>
> - Then it finds `customer_user` model but it has value 3 so it set the value of 2nd parameter with `customer_user::find(3)`
>
> -Then comes $id param and laravel do not have anything to assign so the error comes but when you set `$id=null` which is default value so  you do not get any error
>
> - So now lets edit your `edit` method like this way `public function edit(Request $request, Category $user,  $id)` assuming you have a `Category` model and now visit the same url and check `dd($user->take(1)->first())` you will find category information instead of customer_user!

Comment: Alright now I see, Laravel basically checks the parameter and sees that a model is passed.

Thank you for helping me.